# How to use Convex Hull on Geometry from collection info?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Whenever I use the Group Input node as a geometry source, the convex hull node will wrap around the geometry as a -whole-. However, using the collection info node as the source geometry makes the convex hull wrap around -each- mesh. How can I use collection info and convex hull together so that it wraps around the geometry as a whole?

Group Input as a source (wraps geometry as whole)
[image]

Collection Info as a source (wraps individual objects)
[image]

Comment: Realize instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realize your instances before passing them to the *Convex Hull* node.

[image]